# Merge declined with justification that contradicts the FAQ

Tags: support, merged-questions

[The merge FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/158066/what-is-a-merged-question)<sup>1</sup> says (emphasis mine):

> When should questions be merged?
>
> Questions should be merged if one question is an exact duplicate of
>   another (i.e. **when its answers would make perfect sense on the other
>   question**), and **its answers are high-quality and valuable enough to be
>   included on the other question** itself, **so that good answers aren't
>   forked across multiple copies of the same question.** In order to merge
>   a question, the question to be merged must first be closed as a
>   duplicate of the intended merge target.

Now, this is just the situation with [shipping python modules in pyspark to other nodes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24686474/shipping-python-modules-in-pyspark-to-other-nodes), [How to get python libraries in pyspark?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36217090/how-to-get-python-libraries-in-pyspark) and [Easiest way to install Python dependencies on Spark executor nodes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29495435/easiest-way-to-install-python-dependencies-on-spark-executor-nodes) :

- All these questions are asking the same: how to deploy Python modules onto a `pyspark` cluster.
- All have good answers with intersecting useful info, but answers for each question present some options that are missing from answers to the other questions.

So I marked the latter two to be merged into the former.

A moderator declined the suggestion (though they marked the flag as helpful) with the following justification:

> Merge requests should only be requested on questions that are 100%
>   duplicate and have duplicate answers. The preferred action would be
>   for the domain-experts to vote to close as duplicate.

Which directly contradicts the above FAQ and common sense, too: if the answers are *duplicate*, it makes no sense to merge them into one question. It only makes sense to merge if they rather *complement* each other.

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>Strictly speaking, not officially FAQ atm, but it's the sole question on the meta that covers the topic of merging, and it doesn't look like that its suggestions are being challenged by anyone.</sub>

Comment: Are all answers to question (1) applicable to question (2) and viceversa? I don't think they do.

Comment: Can all answers really be used to answer any of the other questions? Also note, that the quoted text states that all questions have to be closed as duplicates first.

Comment: @Braiam They do. All the questions are asking the same: how to deploy Python modules onto a pyspark cluster nodes. Edited this in.

Comment: @BDL A mod can close the questions single-handedly, so it's not a deal breaker. Closing both first as duplicates the normal way requires disproportionate community resources and is long and unreliable 'cuz the VTC queue is overloaded.

Comment: @BDL Anyway, I VTCed them accordingly, so whoever reads this can help if they wish.